# Why does Ant Design form validation not work when more than one useForm is in the same component?

Tags: forms, validation, react-hooks, antd

I've found that antd's form validation does not always work if I create two form instances by calling useForm() twice in the same scope. [This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-validation-doesnt-work-jhu1h5) demonstrates the issue. To reproduce:

1. Without filling in the field, click Next. You will see a validation error.
2. Fill in a value and click Next. You will go to step 2.
3. Without filling in the field, click Next. You will go to step 3, but you should've gotten a validation error.
4. Click Back to return to step 2.
5. Click Next. Now, it gives a validation error.
6. Fill in the field and click Next.
7. Click Back to return to step 2. Note that the field has retained its value.
8. Click Back to return to step 1. Note that the field will be empty. (Why? This may be related to the issue.)
9. Click Next. No validation error.

From this, I am guessing that the Form component doesn't "know" about the fields in those cases where it fails to validate them. When we return to step 1 and the field is empty, this is a sign that the Form lost track of that field, which is proven when it fails to validate it when you click Next, which had worked originally.

So, is this a bug, a feature, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you only need to use one Form.useForm();
for the "step2Form" form you replace only using "step1Form"

[image: example]

Comment: I agree that in this simple example using a single useForm() resolve the issue, but I'm not convinced that that is the correct/intended pattern. IMO, If the forms in step 1 and step 2 are supposed to be independent of each other, they should have separate form instances. For example, I don't want fields in step 2 to be validated when I validate step 1. 

Regardless, I don't understand why the two instances can't co-exist. It works fine if they are declared in separate scopes, for example. Unfortunately, it's a lot more code to declare them in separate scopes.